# Looking for online image format conversion service like transloadit.com

Tags: service, saas

There are lots of video+audio transcoding SaaS services online, but none of them offers also image format conversion and manipulation.

I'm looking for a service which exposes an API for images conversion and manipulation (at least basic ones such as resize/crop/rotate/thumbnails generation). It would be great if it also will allow automatically push the result to AWS.

The only service I found is http://transloadit.com

It seems great, but before I start using it I'd like to compare prices with other services (if such exist).

*Please notice that I'm looking for **images** conversion out-of-the-box SaaS **service with API**. If it provides both images and video transcoding - great! if it's only for images, also good.

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Thanks.

Max.

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled upon [imgix](http://www.imgix.com/) last weekend. [Their documentation page](http://www.imgix.com/docs) lists examples of commands supplied via the URL, and the [full API](http://www.imgix.com/docs/urlapi)  is documented extensively. Worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

I just found something similar http://cloudinary.com